# No permission for GIT clone submodule

Tags: git, github

**I did the following**

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/XXXX-Lab/bootcamp_XXXX.git
```

The repository is a private repository for which I have access to. However the repository has a submodule in another repository(for which I do not have access)

I was prompted for git username password twice for each of repos

Everything Other than the submodule is cloned.

**Got this**

```
Cloning into 'bootcamp_XXXX'...

Username for 'github.com': XXXX

Password for 'XXXX@github.com': 

remote: Counting objects: 830, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 830 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 828
Receiving objects: 100% (830/830), 14.66 MiB | 3.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (410/410), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule 'XXXX_TUTORIAL' (github.com/XXXX_TUTORIAL/XXXX_TUTORIAL.git) registered for path 'XXXX_TUTORIAL'

Cloning into 'XXXX_TUTORIAL'...

Username for 'github.com': XXXX

Password for 'XXXX@github.com': 

remote: epository not found.
fatal: repository github.com/XXXX_TUTORIAL/XXXX_TUTORIAL.git not found

Clone of 'github.com/XXXX_TUTORIAL/XXXX_TUTORIAL.git' into submodule path 'XXXX_TUTORIAL' failed
```

**Question**

Do I need access to the repository of submodule. Is there a way to clone it since I already have access to main repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need explicit access to the submodule. Having access to the main repository is not enough.